# El operando '>=' no se puede aplicar a operandos del tipo object o int

Tags: c#, windows-forms, linq, datagridview

necesito la solucion para este error:

```
int contar = tablaalumnos.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Count(fila => fila.Cells[6].Value >= 70);
```

Dice que el El operando '>=' no se puede aplicar a operandos del tipo object o int.

Esta linea de codigo debe de contar ciertas filas en un datagridview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El campo [`Value` de un `DataGridViewCell`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.value?view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_DataGridViewCell_Value) es de tipo `object`, no puedes compararlo con un entero sin antes convertirlo a entero.

```
(int)fila.Cells[6].Value >= 70
```

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias, me ha servido.